# Angular + RequireJs + Ui.Router

Tags: angularjs

I've just started using Angular alongside RequireJs and so far I have created a structure that looks like this:

- app.js
- app.core.js
- app.controllers.js
- app.services.js

The core module is where I hinge dependencies and pull in the services and controller modules, like this for example:

```
(function () {
var dependancies = ['angular'];
define(dependancies, function (angular) {
    return angular.module('app.services', [])
        .factory('VehicleService', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
            var stub = {};
            require(['../Angular/Services/VehicleService'], function (VehicleService) {
                angular.extend(stub, $injector.invoke(VehicleService));
            });
            return stub;
        }]);
 });
})();
```

And each service is created in its own file like so:

```
(function () {

define(function () {
    return ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            getAllMakes: function () {
                return $http.get('/Api/RegisteredVehicle/GetAllMakes')
                .success(function (response) {
                    return {
                        vehicleName: response
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }];
});
})();
```

How can I now use `$stateprovider.state.resolve` and get my service instantiated correctly?

```
 .state('quote', {
                     url: '/quote',
                     templateUrl: '/Sales/Dashboard/CreateQuoteVehicle',
                     controller: 'QuoteProposalCtrl as vm',
                     resolve: {
                         vehicleInfo: function () {
                             var stub = {};
                             require(['../Angular/Services/VehicleService'], function (VehicleService) {
                                 angular.extend(stub, $injector.invoke(VehicleService));
                             });
                             return stub;
                         }
                     }
                 })
```

Answer (score 0):

On your core angular module, inject $stateProvider, then put in the states. It should pull in the rest of your dependancies. This should then be loaded as the main starting requirejs file.

```
(function () {
var dependancies = ['angular', 'app.core', 'app.controllers', 'app.services'];
define(dependancies, function (angular) {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['app.core', 'app.controllers', 'app.services']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
     .state('quote', {
                     url: '/quote',
                     templateUrl: '/Sales/Dashboard/CreateQuoteVehicle',
                     controller: 'QuoteProposalCtrl as vm',
                     resolve: {
                         vehicleInfo: function () {
                             var stub = {};
                             require(['../Angular/Services/VehicleService'], function (VehicleService) {
                                 angular.extend(stub, $injector.invoke(VehicleService));
                             });
                             return stub;
                         }
                     }
                 })
});

return app;

})();
```

Depending on your setup you'd be loading the app something like:

```
<script data-main="scripts/app" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

One thing, im not sure you need this require, since it should already be loaded with the app.services dependancy.

```
var stub = {};

require(['../Angular/Services/VehicleService'], function (VehicleService) {
                             angular.extend(stub, $injector.invoke(VehicleService));
                         });
return stub;
```